# How to triger a function automatically by class and id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y92zbpqy/1/)

```
$('#my_id .Alpha').trigger('click');
$(".Alpha").click(function(event) {
  alert('clicked');
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<span id='my_id' class='Alpha'>Test</span>
<span id='my_id' class='Beta'>Test 1</span>
```

According to the jquery

It should click find the element with class name as `Alpha` and id as `my_id`

But it is not triggering. What is the issue and how can i fix this ?

Comment: You cannot have same id for multiple elements

Comment: @VickyGonsalves Yes, but i am having different class name. And finding it by  class name and id name.

Comment: Several issues: 1) An `id` is suppose to be unique. 2) You are triggering the click event before attaching the event listener. 3) Your selector is wrong. It should be `#my_id.Alpha`. 4) You didn't include jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: What's wrong with not using duplicate IDs?!....

Comment: @BizDevB you are missing the point, ids by definition should be unique, as such your html is invalid and therefore any jQuery selector where you are including the id as the first selector, will only return the first element it comes to with that id as it is not expecting to find any more.  If anything, you should keep the classes the same and change the ids - that is the whole point of classes and ids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this:

```
$('#my_id .Alpha').
```

It needs to find an element `.Alpha` **inside** the `#my_id`. Remove the space.

```
$('#my_id.Alpha').
```

This means, the element with `id` as `my_id` **and** `class` as `Alpha` on the **same element**.

Comment: Also, the OP is triggering the click event before the event listener is even attached....

Comment: @JoshCrozier Lemme tell that too.

Comment: @BizDevB Trigger the click after you have attached the function.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need this:

https://jsfiddle.net/y92zbpqy/4/

```
$(".Alpha, .Beta").click(function(event) {
  alert('clicked');
});
```